# How to add a HTTPS to registration page in a web application?

Tags: java, spring, https, tomcat7

I want to add `https` to some certain page of web application.
Application has written with ***Spring*** `3.2.9.RELEASE` version and works under ***Tomcat 7***.

I need move from any `http` page:

> http://app/index.html

to `https` registration page:

> https://app/registration

after this you can move to http as well, for example:

> http://app/presenter.html

I don't need any Authentication and Authorization for this. Just make transport security for this one page. To protect data entered by user.

***What do I need to implement this behavior?***

I don’t know exactly how to integrate that HTTPS part into the application (I have never worked with HTTPS before).

Comment: If you add https only in one page, then you are vulnerable to sslstrip attacks. It's better to add https to the whole website, and using HSTS. It's the only protection against Man in the middle and ssltrip attacks.

Comment: @Tom perhaps you can show some tuning example?

Comment: Not a tomcat specialist, sorry. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html , https://melo.myds.me/wordpress/lets-encrypt-for-tomcat-7-on-ds/  or https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-use-the-certificate-for-tomcat/3677 doesn't help ?

Comment: @Tom I suppose that you are talking about spring security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to configure https support in your Tomcat server. For quick  start you can go with Self Signed Certificates.
To generate self signed certificates in Java, you will find many resources on Internet, but i am referring to following link [How to configure Tomcat to support SSL or https - mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/)

You can generate certificate using Java's keytool utility.

After generating the certificate, configure HTTPS connector in Tomcat.
You need to modify the following file: $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml.
Here you can add the https connector tag or modify the existing one (if it's already uncommented).

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
       keystoreFile="c:\mykeystore"
       keystorePass="password" />
```

After this, you will be able to run tomcat on https.

Now to configure https url in your web app, modify web.xml and add following tag:

```
<security-constraint>

    <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>

    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <!-- Define the context-relative URL(s) to be protected -->
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>

</security-constraint>
```

In  tag you can define your pattern (either all url's to https or specific ones).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This approach doesn't need any spring security configuration?

Comment: Above mentioned web.xml configuration will be interchangeable to enforcing https in spring security. So if you have spring security in your project, you can enable https using it, else you can configure it in your web.xml

Comment: To my opinion spring security configuration is the much more preferable approach here. Because it doesn't need any external configuration, like Tomcat. Just work with project configuration.

Comment: Have you tried that? Because if HTTPS is not configured in Web Server, how spring security can do that.